# Cannot do php upgrade because dependencies error

Tags: apt, dependencies, php, php-fpm

while running `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I stumbled this problem:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5.6-fpm : Depends: php5.6-common (= 5.6.26-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1) but 5.6.28-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

then after I do the suggestion by running `sudo apt-get -f install`, the new error message shows:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5.6-fpm:
 php5.6-fpm depends on php5.6-common (= 5.6.26-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1); however:
  Version of php5.6-common on system is 5.6.28-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1.
dpkg: error processing php5.6-fpm (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 php5.6-fpm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I could not remove `php5.6-fpm` either because it also return `Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

It seems the php5.6-fpm has different dependencies but cannot upgraded or removed because there is a configuration missing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 1):

A way to meet all required dependencies, is to install the lamp package by running the command below (including the `^` symbol)

`sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`